# Just go to the target once and it should go 4 times. Picasso/Target

Tags: android, picasso

So I implement picasso, so I can download images and save them on sd cart, so when I want i can use them on the program.

I have a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaProdutos.size(); i++) {
                caminho =listaProdutos.get(i).getImagem();
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("URL"+listaProdutos.get(i).getImagem()).into(target);
            }
```

But I just get into target once and its the last one of for loop,

target code:

```
private Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            //new Thread(new Runnable() {
                //@Override
                //public void run() {
            /*
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(),caminho);
                    try
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                        ostream.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    try {
                        verifyStoragePermissions(AtividadePrincipal.this);
                        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(root + "/imagensDaApp");
                        myDir = new File(myDir, caminho);
                        if (!myDir.exists()) {
                            myDir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                        //myDir.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                //}
            //}).start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
            }
        }
    };
```

I commented the thread because it does the same thing with or without, if you want you cant uncomment.

I have alredy search about it, but i couldnt find any answer for this problem, all the URL are ok!

I have been been doing this for 3 days, and it keep the same.

**YES listaProdutos.size() = 4;
AND all the url are ok!**

If u didnt understand the question, please say.

Comment: I think that Picasso itself filters requests with duplicated targets. You'll have to create 4 instances of target to do what you want

Comment: @VladMatvienko but in this case is 4 but maybe the user wants to add 5 or 6, I dont know how many it will be

Comment: you need to create new target inside the cycle. This way you'll create as much as you need.

Comment: I've posted an answer

Comment: Also don't use non-English names in your code if you want StackOverflow to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the following code? No Targets are used here, so no target is getting gc'ed

I took the freedom to optimize your code a little as well. I've done this without testing the code, but it should work without any problems.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
              @Override
              public void run(){

                for (int i = 0; i < listaProdutos.size(); i++) {
                                caminho =listaProdutos.get(i).getImagem();

                                try {
                                    verifyStoragePermissions(AtividadePrincipal.this);
                                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                    File myDir = new File(root + "/imagensDaApp");
                                    myDir = new File(myDir, caminho);
                                    if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                        if(myDir.getParentFile().mkdirs()){
                                           //myDir.createNewFile();
                                           FileOutputStream out = null;
                                           out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                                           Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("URL"+listaProdutos.get(i).getImagem()).get().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                           out.flush();
                                           out.close();
                                        }

                                    }

                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }catch{IOException  e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
              }
            }).start();
```

Comment: Tnx, this work for me, You just need to change some code, and I will accept this as an answer :) In my case I didn't need those "if"but thats ok to let stay, the "catch" didn't work like that, pls change to catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } And them I will accept it :)

Comment: @FranciscoMelicias Changed it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class implementingTarget:

```
class MyTarget implements Target {
        String name;
        public MyTarget(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            //new Thread(new Runnable() {
                //@Override
                //public void run() {
            /*
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(),caminho);
                    try
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                        ostream.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    try {
                        verifyStoragePermissions(AtividadePrincipal.this);
                        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(root + "/imagensDaApp");
                        myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                        if (!myDir.exists()) {
                            myDir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                        //myDir.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                //}
            //}).start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
            }
        }
    };
```

And use it inside the cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaProdutos.size(); i++) {
                caminho =listaProdutos.get(i).getImagem();
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("URL"+listaProdutos.get(i).getImagem()).into(new MyTarget(caminho ));
            }
```

Comment: how do i send a String to this class?

Comment: @FranciscoMelicias, what is varivel ?

Comment: @FranciscoMelicias create a setter in a class, and save the value into a field. `something.setString("your string here");`

Comment: @FranciscoMelicias, or you may pass it into a constructor. Do you need to pass your `caminho`?

Comment: yes, i need it, caminho means path sorry for non.english